# Is my brand new Indian passport damaged due to a loose thread in the middle of the booklet?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, indian-citizens, airports, india

[image]

So basically I applied for a new passport and I got it two months ago. I was flipping through the pages a few days ago and I realized that there is a loose dangling thread in the lower part of the booklet if you look carefully. So far the passport is tight and is in mint condition but I want to know that if one stitch is broken, wouldn't all the stitches come out eventually?

I'm worried as getting a passport in India can be a bit daunting due to police verification and overburdened administrative system and I don't want to go through the whole process again.

So can I try my luck in travelling with this passport? Do you guys think it can survive for 10 years? I rarely take it outside of my folder but I'm worried that after a few visa stamps and a few more scans of this passport, all the stitches might come out.

What should I do?

Also can I apply for a student visa now with this passport? As the embassy and the immigration officers usually stretch out the entire booklet to put a stamp/visa on it will it make the threading even more loose?

Maybe I'm overreacting on a tiny piece of loose thread but I would really like to hear your 2 cents on the condition of my passport.

Comment: Are you sure it is a broken thread and not just the terminating end? The picture is too coarse to observe that.

Comment: Well my previous passport doesn't have this loose thread. It really seems like that one of the stitches came out.

Answer (score 10):

**No**, it is fine.

Cut the extra piece of thread with sharp scissors and be done with it. It was already supposed to be cut but somehow the machine didn’t cut it cleanly so you can finish the job.

If that was considered a damage then thousands of passports every day would be rejected. Don’t think too much of it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. Tried to cut it it but the thread is kind of strong and I didn't wanted to mess with it further so I left it as it is. But in case it is a loose stitch, does that mean that the entire booklet will fall off one  time or later?

Comment: No it isn’t a lose stitch it’s jus an extra part which was supposed to be trimmed off after the stitching was compeleted. Although I have no first hand experience of an Indian passport but all booklets are like that. I believe it’s no big deal. And it won’t fall off all of a sudden one day. I would ignore it.